# Is there a way to handle Toolbar Button Events in a WinForms App in a file/class other than the form's code behind?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a C# WinForms app that has a lot (60+) of ToolBar and Menu controls that (obviously) will need to have event handlers attached to them. If I put all of these in the form's code behind file it is really going to clutter it up and make it hard to navigate around within it. Is there a better way to create event handlers in another class/file in order to help keep the form's code behind module a little cleaner?

Comment: You can delegate the actions to appropriate class which responsible   for each toolbar actions. See Command pattern. The partial class also can do trick (not recommended).

Comment: Thanks Hamlet. Would you mind adding your comment as response so that I can mark it as the answer? Also, would you please provide a bit of code explaining how you would go about delegating the event handler to another class. I have thought about that approach but figured that I would have to modify the designer file. Not sure how I feel bout that. I too thought about the partial class approach but ruled it out almost immediately.